# Unable to process upgrades due to error with snmpd

Tags: 14.04, updates, snmp

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server edition. Just recently started getting these errors with snmpd:

```
Setting up snmpd (5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1) ...
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (1) do not match snmpd Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
 * Starting network management services:                                                                                                          invoke-rc.d: initscript snmpd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package snmpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libsvn1:amd64 (1.8.8-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up subversion (1.8.8-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snmpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output of apt-cache policy snmpd:

```
root@maleficent:/home/dlanier# apt-cache policy snmpd
snmpd:
  Installed: 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy snmpd`

Comment: same problem here. `apt-cache policy snmpd` returns already installed and same candidate version, and 500 security.ubuntus. Nothing fancy i guess... can't copy paste everything in here. I guess his question is how to fix these error msgs.

Comment: Nobody seems to know how to fix. I am looking at the possibility of spinning up a new server and migrating everything instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

1. `sudo dpkg --purge snmp`

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     libmysqlclient18 libperl5.18 libsnmp30 mysql-common
   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
     snmpd*
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
   1 not fully installed or removed.
   After this operation, 232 kB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
   ```

   Whoops.... its perl, mysql and the snmp lib.
2. `sudo apt-get purge snmpd`

   Get rid of that too. Not only the config files.
3. If you want to get rid of the `AUTOREMOVE` messages and/or you actually need the packages just remove and reinstall the packages.

   `sudo apt-get autoremove`

   Modify as you please:

   `sudo apt-get install libperl5.18 libsnmp30 libmysqlclient18 mysql-common`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @proxylittle The problem eventually seemed to correct itself through normal updates and security patches for me.

Comment: Nice to hear that. For me it still persisted though (vm). Might help somebody else i guess.